Using a library that scrapes from Tableau websites results to fetching empty worksheet/dataframes, but I am able to fetch on the website itself
My code goes like this:
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = 'https://embi.iemop.ph/t/Public/views/RT_DASH/RT_DASH?:isGuestRedirectFromVizportal=y&:embed=y'

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
workbook = ts.getWorkbook()

for t in workbook.worksheets:
    print(f"worksheet name : {t.name}") #show worksheet name
    print(t.data) #show dataframe for this worksheet

The dataframe output for each worksheet is empty, but I am able to fetch the csv files from the website manually (with data present in them). I figure that this is a URL problem since doing this to other Tableau dashboards gives me no such problem.
I tried snipping off bits from the URL but to no avail
